# How to remove items from a shopping cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When i click to remove a item all items are removed from *cartObjects*. I am not understanding they are all removed and not only the one with the matching id. Please guide me through this problem.

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandArgument.ToString().ToLower() == "remove")
    {
       GetCartId(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandName));
    }

 }

 private void GetCartId(int CartId)
 {

    cartObjects.RemoveAll(i => i.Id == CartId);
    Repeater1.DataBind();
 }

protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetCartId(CartId);

}
```

I am importing my data through webapi.
    Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have you checked that all items are having different ids? ; ) and are the items really removed (cartObjects.Count ==0) or do you just don't see the result? Btw what type is  cartObjects? When is it created?

Comment: Items have different ids

Comment: Make a breakoing after cartObjects remove and check wether it still has items after the remove. Its improtant to know wether it is a display or code issue. As the code looks ok at first look i think its a dispaly issue or that the cartObjects instance gets recreated / lost. What Type is cartObjects? Can you provide more code showing how cart object is defined?

Comment: No there are no items it shows null

Comment: List<ProductModel> cartObjects = new List<ProductModel>();

Comment: null ? or you mean 0 (zero) ? What type is Product id ?

Comment: Product id is of integer type

Comment: I checked the condition for cartObjects.Count==0 and it is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
cartObjects.Where(x => x.Id != CartId).ToList();
```

You should be able to filter all items having Id equal to "CartId" with above.